# How to find google chrome or firefox tab url by terminal(ubuntu or windows)?

Tags: node.js, windows, google-chrome, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

Actually i want to get url of browser from any terminal command .Suppose i am running google chrome with many tabs ,i want to get current focus url data .Plz provide any solution

Answer (score -1):

Because you mentioned:

> ... from any terminal command

I suggest a Python library named [BroTab](https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab):

```
$ pip install --user brotab
$ bt install
```

You need to install browser extensions then: [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brotab/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/brotab/mhpeahbikehnfkfnmopaigggliclhmnc/).

After all you will be able to list tabs and active ones with `bt list`, `bt active` from any terminal.